# What is wrong with this C code segment? When I am not assigning t it is working fine

Tags: c, pointers

This is the erroneous code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int* t = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int a = 4;
    t = &a;
    printf("%d\n",*t);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you set `t` to point to `a`, you don't need the dynamic memory allocation. Get rid of the `(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));` as well as the `free(t);`.

Comment: If you want to test the dynamic memory management, the line should be `*t = a;` to copy the value of `a` to the memory where `t` points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens in your code:

A pointer t points to an int which is created dynamically

```
int* t = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Data:

```
t -> INT
```

A new variable is created

```
int a = 4;
```

Data:

```
t -> unnamed: integer
           a: 4
```

T is assigned to a

```
t = &a;
```

Data:

```
    unnamed: integer
t->       a: 4
```

This causes a problem, because the dynamically created integer is not referred anymore to. There is also no way to free it now there is no variable pointer to it.

(Trying to) free memory

```
free(t);
```

Data:

```
    unnamed: integer
t->       a: 4
```

Memory cannot be freed because it points to stack space (for in this case local variable), not heap space (for dynamic variables). See comment of Jeremy below.

Solution:

Do not use the malloc and free, and assign t (as pointer) to variable a, after you create a.

Comment: The problem at the end is not that there is a variable still assigned to the memory pointed to by `t` but that the memory was allocated from the stack, not the heap. You can't free it.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` and `calloc` are used for dynamic memory allocation for arrays. As Blaze said in comments, just removing `malloc` will solve your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int* t;
    int a = 4;
    t = &a;
    printf("%d\n",*t);
    return 0;
}
```

You won't need `free` as well, because, you did not allocate dynamic memory. Moreover, if you do create dynamic memory for array, I would recommend you to use `calloc` over `malloc`, as unlike `malloc`, `calloc` initializes memory with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, there are three types of memory available to a C program.

- memory for global and static variables
- "automatic" memory for function local variables and parameters
- dynamic memory which is allocated by the program code itself using functions like `malloc()`.

Automatic memory (I call it that because there used to be a keyword in C `automatic` you could use to specify it) is allocated automatically from the program stack or the CPU's register file when a function is entered and automatically deallocated when the function is left.

Dynamic memory is allocated from the "heap" which is basically just a heap of memory not in any particular order.

In your code you have automatic and dynamic allocations:

```
int* t = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This code allocates memory for a pointer on the stack (`t`) and enough memory for an `int` from the heap. A pointer to that memory is saved in `t`

```
int a = 4;
```

This code allocates memory for an `int` on the stack (`a`) and saves the `int` 4 in it.

```
t = &a;
```

This code gets a pointer to `a` (which is allocated from the stack) and stores it in `t`.

Note that the previous content of `t` the pointer to the dynamically allocated block of memory from the heap has now been lost. There is now no way for your program to deallocate the heap memory. This is called a memory leak and, in larger programs, bugs of this nature cause the memory usage to keep going up until the system grinds to a halt or the program fails because it can't be allocated any more heap memory.

```
printf("%d\n",*t);
```

This just prints out what is pointed to by `t` i.e `a` which is 4.

```
free(t);
```

`free()` is used by the C library to return memory that was allocated from the heap back to the heap. Unfortunately, `t` no longer points to memory from the heap, it points to memory on the stack. It's likely that this line corrupts the heap. Were you not about to exit the program, it would be a disaster.